# Inner product inequality involving linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

$V$ is an inner product space and $\tau \in \mathcal {L}(V)$. I want to show that for any unit vector $v\in V$, $\langle \tau v, v\rangle\langle v,\tau v\rangle\leq\langle \tau v,\tau v\rangle$. I tried to extend the eigenvectors of $\tau$ to a basis for $V$ and write $v$ as a linear combination of this basis. But I don't know how to deal with the vectors that are in the basis but are not the eigenvectors of $\tau$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $\langle v, \tau v \rangle = \overline{\langle \tau v, v \rangle}$ and the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: OMG, thank you. So the equality holds when $\tau v$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, right? This is to say that $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tau$.

Comment: Welcome! And yes, you're right.