# $V$ is a inner product space, prove $\langle av, v\rangle \langle v, av\rangle \le \langle av, av\rangle $

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Here is the problem

---

$V$ is an inner product space, and a is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. Prove that for any unit vector $v$ belongs to $V$, we have $\langle av, v\rangle \langle v, av\rangle  \le \langle av, av\rangle$.

---

The textbook I am reading on talks nothing about the product of two inner products. But I assume that $\langle v, v\rangle \langle v, v\rangle = |\langle v, v\rangle|^2$, is that right?

---

I think this problem has to discuss two circumstances, one is where $\langle av, v\rangle = 0$, so both sides equal to $0$, that is an equivalent, but what about the other case when $\langle av, v\rangle$ is not equal to $0$, where the left hand side less than the right hand side?

Comment: By the way, what info can I have from "unit vector"? ‹v, v›  = 1?

Comment: $V$ is a space over what field?  $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: You wrote |<v,v>|^2; did you realize <v,v> must be a non-negative real number?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127021/inner-product-inequality-involving-linear-operator.

Comment: Why to choose that horrible, confusing letter for a linear map??

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The question didn't mention over R or C. And I know <v,v> is non-negative, but the textbook has a similar expression.

Comment: @DonAntonio because I am new here, not knowing how to type greek letter, sorry

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks!

Comment: Greek letter \$\alpha\$ = $\alpha$

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth cannot comment at that post. Can I ask you a question? If  is a linear transformation from V to V, then do we have  = ?

Comment: @PixieBlade In general that will not be the case.

Comment: No need of greek letters at all. What about simply $\;T\;$ ? Then  itd be $\;Tv\;$ instead of $\;av\;$ ...

Comment: Observe that $$\langle Tv,v\rangle\langle v,Tv\rangle=\langle Tv,v\rangle\overline{\langle Tv,v\rangle}=\left|\langle Tv,v\rangle\right|^2$$ so the inequality makes sense as it is real numbers in both sides.

Comment: @DonAntonio Do you when would be the condition when the left hand side equal to the right hand side?